# HybridAuth unexpected session behavior

Tags: php, session, oauth, hybridauth

I was trying to make HybridAuth forget last user login, but nothing worked!! then I noticed very strange session behavior when using HybridAuth:

**1- HybridAuth Sessions are not destroyed even when using session_destroy:**

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);  //Session Values before authentication

require_once("hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php");
$config = 'hybridauth/config.php'; 

$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
$google = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Google" );

session_unset();
session_destroy();

var_dump($_SESSION);  //Session values after destroy
```

The Output:

```
Session Values before authentication!
array (size=2)
  'HA::CONFIG' => 
    array (size=3)
    < ----- content here ------>
  'HA::STORE' => 
    array (size=5)
    < ----- content here ------>

Session values after destroy
array (size=0)
    empty
```

I get session values even before initializing Hybrid_Auth class. And when I refresh the page same values remain although it appears that the values where cleared at the end of the code.

**2- Infinite redirect loop when you clear session at start**

```
session_start();
session_destroy();

require_once( "hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php" );
$config = 'hybridauth/config.php'; 

$hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );
$google = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Google" );
```

When I run the above code I get **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error!

What is going on here?

Answer (score 7):

You can clear Hybrid Auth Session for all providers at once by calling

```
$this->load->library('hybridauthlib');

$this->hybridauthlib->logoutAllProviders();
```

or

you can remove session for a specific provider by modifying your Auth.php file with this method

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
* A generic function to logout from a specific provider 
*/ 

public static function logoutFromProvider($provider)
{
    $adapter = Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter( $provider );

    $adapter->logout();
}
```

You can then call this method like this

```
//$provider can be Facebook, Twitter, Google etc.
public function logout($provider)
{
    $this->hybridauthlib->logoutFromProvider($provider);
}
```